# php fputcsv is trims the string value while writing to file

Tags: php, file, fputcsv

I don't know this question is asked or not. I didn't get his in suggestion.

I'm trying to write some data from database to an csv file.
I'm using `fputcsv` function.

I'm using following code :

```
$fh = @fopen($fileName, 'w+');
        $writeText['sku'] = $somevalue
        $writeText['attribute_set'] = $somevalue
        $writeText['type'] = $somevalue
        $writeText['default_catalogue_link']= $somevalue
        $writeText['status'] = $somevalue
@fputcsv($fh, $writeText);
        @flush();
@fclose($fh);
```

Some of the values starts with zero like `$writeText['sku']` is `0987`.
After writing to the file. I'm getting `987` in the file.

how to prevent this? I need with zero values.

Any help would be usefull.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `$writeText['sku'] = (string)$somevalue;`

Comment: If that doesn't work and you know that all skus are 4 digits you could use `str_pad()` to maintain a leading zero.  Or I believe if you ensure that the values are encapsulated as strings (with quotes) in the CSV they should keep the leading zeros.

Comment: (string)somevalue is not working. Not all the values are of 4digits

Comment: Eek, you'll probably need to make sure the CSV has the numbers encapsulated in quotes then.

Comment: I tried `$writeText['sku'] = " ".$somevalue;` also, its not working. I'm not getting how to encapsulate with qoutes :-(

Comment: Stop using those damn error supression operators; if you get an error, its something you need to FIX, not ignore/supress

Comment: For instance, if your csv looks like this: `0987,"Something"` try changing it to this `"0987","Something"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Excel to open the file? Because Excel interprets it as a number. Try open and see with a text editor.

Comment: nothing wrong with the code? check all those error supression operators! -.-

Comment: sorry, i was trying to say that the data might still be in the csv even if he doesn't see it in the correct format.
For an example I once tried to get the string "536775212172206080" on a csv and it was showing 5.37E+17 but the number was still there when I check with a text editor.

Comment: @Sanura Yes, you are right. It's showing properly in text editor, I wanted use that file as input for another application, Its working fine. :-) Thanks